# Transactions vs FieldValue.increment(1) in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Which one of the following methods is safer to be used in order to increment the value of a counter by one, a transaction or FieldValue.increment(1)? Or do this methods do the exact same thing? Are there any downsides when using the second option? I'm asking this because literally I use a single line of code vs. min 15 in case of transaction. Thanks!

Comment: The old'fashion transaction is more flexible, you can perform additional checks before updating a document. But if you just want to increment a counter, then the all of the boilerplate is useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have the exact same effect in the end.  `FieldValue.increment` is more efficient because it doesn't require an extra round trip between the client and server in order to process the transaction handler callback on the client.